# Get ApplicationBasePath in a DNX PCL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

In a DNX asp.net app the base directory would be be dependency injected in as a `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath`

How can you get the equivalent in a DNX portable class library - which doesn't have a startup class?

`"./"` and the like isn't suitable as it would point to the base directory of the host app referencing the PCL, not the base of the PCL itself.

Asking in context of supplying it to a `ConfigurationBuilder`, to pick up a `Config.json` in the PCL's root directory (from within a repository)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this right now. I've used something like `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("..\\MyOtherProject")` for migrations and stuff as a lame workaround.

Comment: Yeah, that's I'm doing too, it's not great though..

Answer (score 1):

If the PCL requires configuration, it should be the main application that has that configuration or at the very least, supplies it to the PCL.

Even the first versions of .NET doesn't work that way. The configurations are always from the invoking assemblies.

This hasn't changed in ASP.NET 5/DNX. If you need to find a specific file, you'll need to either start to locate assemblies or navigate from the invoking application.